# FTS3 setup on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, fts3

I am trying to use FTS3 in SQLite. The virtual table is created using sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win.

`CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tbl1 USING FTS3 ( col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT);`

When I insert some data it says: `no such module FTS3`

`insert into tbl1(col1, col2) values ('c1', 'c2');`

Answer (score 0):

That SQLite Database Browser apparently has not been compiled with FTS.
Anyway, it's outdated.

Use some up-to-date tool, like the [sqlite3 command-line shell](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html), or the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Firefox addon.

Comment: sqlite3 command-line shell is a tool. I am looking to develop a program in c# that can use FTS3 of sqlite. e.g. System.Data.Sqlite is dll that can be used in c# to communicate with SQLite database. This dll does not provide functionality for FTS3.